# Angular JS ng-switch with ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 3 different code fragments which I'd like to swap out depending on the selection in a select menu.

It works if I include the code inline, but when I try to use ng-includes like this, I get an Angular error and the app fails:

```
      <div ng-switch on="pFilter">
      <div ng-include="'includes/parcel_details_incoming.html'" ng-switch-when="Incoming Parcels"></div>
      <div ng-include="'includes/parcel_details_forward.html'" ng-switch-when="Exception Parcels"></div>
      <div ng-include="'includes/parcel_details_exception.html'" ng-switch-default></div>
      </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Does ng-switch not work with ng-includes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is both the directives `ng-include` and `ng-switch-x` use transclusion and you are specifying both on the same element and it is not allowed. Move nginclude to the child of ng-switch element.

```
   <div ng-switch on="pFilter">
      <div  ng-switch-when="Incoming Parcels"><div ng-include="'includes/parcel_details_incoming.html'"></div></div>
      <div  ng-switch-when="Exception Parcels"><div ng-include="'includes/parcel_details_forward.html'"></div></div>
      <div  ng-switch-default><div ng-include="'includes/parcel_details_exception.html'"></div></div>
   </div>
```

This used to work until angular 1.x version but compound transclusion will result in *multidir* error starting 1.2.x version of angular. Take a look at the [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-bug-fixes-67) and this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/63c5334c84b7269428c710226764d1f08a36e0d4).